# How to modify the color of a 9patch image Android ?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't really understand how to create a 9patch image, but I found an image which is working on my fragment. The problem is that the color outside the border is not the color of the background. I tried changing the color of the pixels from the image to the color of the background but the resulting image doesn't work anymore. 
This is the image which is working but has the wrong color:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJBfV.png

How can I change the color of the pixels that are outside the border, or how can I create a new 9patch image that looks like that ?

Comment: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Answer (score 10):

You can use `DrawableCompat` with supprot v4.

The next code shows how you can change `Toast` color.
As you know, toast background is a 9patch `Drawable` named `toast_frame.9.png` (you can find it in your sdk dir).

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toastView.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
View toastView = toast.getView();
Drawable toastBg = toastView.getBackground();
Drawable drawable = tintDrawable(toastBg, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
toastView.setBackground(drawable);
toast.setView(toastView);
toast.show();

public  Drawable tintDrawable(Drawable drawable, ColorStateList colors) {
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, colors);
    return wrappedDrawable;
}
```

If you like to learn more, click this:
http://www.race604.com/tint-drawable

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the 9 patch using the Draw 9-patch tool that is provided with the Android SDK. However as your image already includes the 9 patch stretchable area you can just edit the colors in an image editor, such as GIMP or Photoshop. Ensure you rename your image to use the `.9.png` extension to allow it to be recognized as a 9 patch image.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

Nine-patch are normal png files. They are just interpreted differently by any software able to display nine-patch. In other words, you can edit them with any png editor.

There is also some dedicated tools (for instance: in android sdk /tools/draw9patch) that display the result in different sizes.

How are they interpreted then ?

The first and last rows + the first and last columns of pixels in a nine-patch image contains only black or transparent pixels (and those first/last rows/columns aren't displayed).

The (*intersection of*) black pixels on left and top edges defines stretchable areas. (you can have more than one)

The (*intersection of*) black pixels on right and bottom edges define the content area. (you can only have one)

Comment: I changed the color of some pixels through photoshop and I saved the edited image as a png, but when I modified the name to be .9.png android wasn't able to find the file

Comment: what do you mean by "unable to find" ?

Comment: In android -> Couldn't find the file in your drawable folder. This happened after I modified the color in photoshop